# How to configure Windows 8 me to ask when I want update to be run?

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, windows-update

Maybe it is Murphy's law that whenever I need to shutdown my laptop and leave as soon as possible (to catch a bus or something:) ) Windows always starts updating and it takes ages. It is very annoying to wait for Windows to finish the update.

Is it possible on **Windows 8** to configure that Windows would ask when I would like to run the available update: right after clicking on or on the next shutdown/restart?

If I am not wrong, there is a similar option on Windows Vista (I guess) that shows an exclamation mark next to the shutdown button that tells the user that an update will be performed when I click on shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure Windows to only notifiy you before downloading the updates. [Now install this tool](http://www.quppa.net/wunotify/) to get the notification icon in the systray back, which whas removed in Windows 8.

[image]

Now you get notified about new updates and if you don't want to install them, ignore it and shutdown Windows.